# Django: sorl-thumbnail image not updated right away because of cache

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I have a `ModelA` which has sorl-thumbnail `ImageField`.

I load this model's images using `sorl thumbnail` in templates.

Problem is that whenever I change the image of this model, its new image doesn't show up right away because of brower cache (I think...)

How can I make it shown up right away after change the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

press `ctrl`+`shift`+`R` for a hard reload. that usually works for me. but if it didn't work, just open chrome's inspect element tool by `ctrl`+`shift`+`I` and then right click on the refresh button and click on `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` as in the below picture.

[image: Empty cache]